# @ConfigurationProperties in spring boot WAR project

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat9

I want to use `@ConfigurationProperties` and bind some properties in `application.properties` to that class. When I exclude embedded tomcat dependency from `pom.xml`, I cant use those properties defined in `@ConfigurationProperties` class. How can I solve the problem when using an external tomcat?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the `@ConfigurationProperties` that works regardless your deployment.

Comment: with WAR style deployment, the Configuration class returns null for its properties.

Comment: Regardless it should work, if it doesn't work you are doing things differently than you should be doing them. Without seeing what you do or knowning the location of your `application.properties` this will be impossible to answer. In short it should work, if it doesn't work it is due to how you have structured things (as a general rule of thumb).